# Blazor - Copying Razor Page Causes Error 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, .net-6.0

I have a brand new .Net6 Blazor App, rendered side, with a newly added page at  `/pages/scorer.razor` which runs and debugs without issue.

When I copy the `.razor` page to a new page, eg from `/pages/scorer.razor` to `/pages/mudscorer.razor`, the following error is thrown when attempting to debug the application:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Source: `/pages/scorer.razor`

```cs
@page "/Scorer"
@attribute [Authorize()]
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Scoring")]
<PageTitle>MudScorer</PageTitle>

<link href="css/SleepCareStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
    #dimScreen {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="SmallHeader">Scorer's Work List</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ScorerWorkList></ScorerWorkList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Source: `/pages/mudscorer.razor`

```cs
@page "/Scorer"
@attribute [Authorize()]
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Scoring")]
<PageTitle>MudScorer</PageTitle>

<link href="css/SleepCareStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
    #dimScreen {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="SmallHeader">Scorer's Work List</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ScorerWorkList></ScorerWorkList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the issue. Please add an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `@page` directive unique otherwise the router won't know how to route requests for /Scorer

> Source: /pages/mudscorer.razor

```
@page "/MudScorer" 
        ^^^
    for example
```

Incidentally, not sure why you didn't get a bit more help out of the subsystem. When I make duplicated @page directives I see:

[image]

<sub>It's one of my favorite runtime errors to cause these days - that and adding some new thing, forgetting to register it in DI and getting *Cannot provide a value for property 'X' on type 'Y'. There is no registered service of type 'Z'*. Classic copy pasta mistake, every time!</sub>

Comment: The problem is Net6 has taken a backward step here.  No nice exception message any more.  I've logged an issue and it has been acknowledged.  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38380